# Can I create a `gramex` `microservice` that automatically takes the subdirectories and renders the `markdown` in them?

Tags: gramex

I am trying to create a `Gramex` application. The intention is to:

1. See the root folder `readme.md` page when I access `localhost:9988` (local `gramex` generic port)
2. See the `readme.md` in `subdir1` when I access `localhost:9988/subdir1/`
3. See the `readme.md` in `subdir2` when I access `localhost:9988/subdir2/`

For that I have a `gramex.yaml` file, that reads

```yaml
url:
  app:
    pattern: /$YAMLURL/
    handler: FileHandler
    kwargs:
      index: false
      path:
        "": $YAMLPATH/{dir}/readme.md
      transform:
        "*.md":
          encoding: utf-8
          function: markdown.markdown(content)
          headers:
            Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
      default:
        dir: ""
        file: readme
        ext: md
```

Here `localhost:9988` renders the root folder `readme.md`.
However, browsing `localhost:9988:subdir1` renders the directory index, implying that `subdirs` are not working.
Wondering if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 3 things:

1. `pattern: /$YAMLURL/` should be `pattern: /$YAMLURL/.*`. Otherwise, no other URL will match
2. `path: "": $YAMLPATH/{dir}/readme.md` is not required
3. `default:` is not a kwarg. Use `default_filename: readme.md`

Here's a working configuration:

```yaml
url:
  app:
    pattern: /$YAMLURL/(.*)
    handler: FileHandler
    kwargs:
      path: $YAMLPATH
      default_filename: README.md
      transform:
        "*.md":
          encoding: utf-8
          function: markdown.markdown(content)
          headers:
            Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The documentation is at https://gramener.com/gramex/guide/filehandler/